# have an error about locating the package during the install

Tags: apt

I want to install `libnet`. I wrote in terminal:

```
sudo apt install libnet
```

but this error is happen:

```
Unable to locate package libnet
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Libnet is a high-level API (toolkit) allowing the construction and injection of network packets. In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu libnet is provided by *libnet1* (library for the construction and handling of network packets). Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install libnet1
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because there is actually no package with only that name, there are many packages with the name `libnet` like `libnet1` and `libnet1-dbg`.

When you write `sudo apt-get install libnet` in the terminal, double press the button <kbd>Tab</kbd> to see all the other packages with that name and choose the one you want/need.